# How can I find pattern when Regex reads digits as string type?

Tags: python, pdf, python-re

I am trying to code a pdf reader script. When I write the pattern in RE, it returns nothing.

Input:

```
import requests
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import re

with pdfplumber.open("file.pdf") as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()

decl = re.compile(r'\d{8}AN\d{6}')

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if decl.search(line):
        print(line)
```

Searched text line from pdf file is 'CHEMISCHE FABRIK BUDENHEIM KG PO BOX 61245366AN206589'

But it does not return the required output of: 61245366AN206589

I found out that it reads the whole line as string. How can I work around this?

```
for char in text.split('\n')[3]:
    print(char)
    print(type(char))
```

.
.
.
<class 'str'>
B
<class 'str'>
O
<class 'str'>
X
<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
6
<class 'str'>
1
<class 'str'>
2
<class 'str'>
4
<class 'str'>
5
<class 'str'>
3
<class 'str'>
6
<class 'str'>
6
<class 'str'>
A
<class 'str'>
N
<class 'str'>
2
<class 'str'>
0
<class 'str'>
6
<class 'str'>
5
<class 'str'>
8
<class 'str'>
9
<class 'str'>

Comment: How are you using the compiled regex? If you're using ```match()``` it matches from the beginning of the string. You may need ```search()``` instead.

Comment: Please show us your real code -- something we can copy-and-paste to run ourselves..  By just including snippets like this, it's way too easy for you to hide the mistakes you have made.  Your `for` loop is producing exactly what it should produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search` returns a match object, so if there is a match, you need to extract the result from that.

Here it is in an interactive session:

```
>>> decl = re.compile(r"\d{8}AN\d{6}")
>>> m = decl.search("CHEMISCHE FABRIK BUDENHEIM KG PO BOX 61245366AN206589")
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(37, 53), match='61245366AN206589'>
>>> m.group(0)
'61245366AN206589'
>>> m.span()
(37, 53)
```

The `span` is the location of the match in the search text, using slice notation values.